# Convert class with interface field to protobuf

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java, proto, protobuf-java

I have a class with interface field and the interface has multiple implementations. I need to convert my class to protobuf, but I am not able to map the interface field, which is actually a type interface.
Here is my Java code for class structure:

```
class A {
   String name;
   String occupation;
   Operable operable;
}
interface operable {
}
class OperableA implements operable {
    String job;
    List<String> tasks; 
}
class OperableB implements operable {
    int numberOfWorkers;
    List<String> skills;
    List<String> nameOfWorkers;
}
```

How can this structure be mapped in proto file, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot model class or interface inheritance in protobuf as described [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#defining-your-protocol-format) which says

> Don't go looking for facilities similar to class inheritance, though – protocol buffers don't do that.